# man page - grotty error: character above first line discarded

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext, manpage

When building the Chapel language documentation for Chapel with Sphinx as man page, I encounter the following errors:

```
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :1756: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :1760: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :1764: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :4794: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :4798: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :4802: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :5505: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :5509: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :5513: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :7137: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :7141: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :7145: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :7892: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :7896: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :7900: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :12168: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :12172: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :12176: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :14254: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :14258: character above first line discarded
grotty:<standard input> (path/to/man3/chapel.3) :14262: character above first line discarded
```

I can't seem to pin down what is causing this error specifically. [Here is a link](https://gist.github.com/ben-albrecht/bbbeae0e0b45db46f84ab2997fff95b8) to the man page I have generated with sphinx. If I can figure out what is causing the error, I imagine I'll be able to modify the source to prevent it in some way.

Comment: Also see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/547608/grotty-man-page-messages/1115710#1115710

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is due to a bug in the `grotty` program, where it did not accept vertical lines that exceeded a page length. I found this out from a debian bug report back in 2012: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=673436

I was able to prevent the error from occurring by prepending my man page file with:

```
.if n .pl 2000v
```

This effectively makes `grotty`  think the page breaks are actually really big (2000 units), so that it never complains about vertical lines that exceed the default length.

Hope this helps someone some day.